# hibby jibby 123456789

Tags: php

I am currently trying to create an application that can shorten a word with its abbreviation 
   that is stored in an external text file. The word can be followed by punctuation
   characters which should also be retained after shortening.

I am unable to have the method return the original word if it cannot find an 
   abbreviation for it. By the looks of it the method isn't reaching my final return statement and
   I am unsure why.

```
public class WordShortener {


private Scanner fileIn;
private String shortenedWord ="";
private String s="";

    public WordShortener() throws Exception {
    // to be completed
    Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File("abbs.txt"));
    this.fileIn = fileIn;
    }

public String wordShortener( String WordToShorten ) {
    // to be completed
        String s = wordToShorten;
            String shortened ="";
        while ( shortenedWord.equals(WordToShorten) && fileIn.hasNextLine()  ) {
            String line = fileIn.nextLine();
            String punctuationChar="";
            String[] lines = line.split(",");
            String originalWord = lines[0];
            String shortenedWord = lines[1];
            String punctuations = "'?.";

            if ( punctuations.contains(s.substring(s.length() - 1)) ) {
                punctuationChar = s.substring(s.length() - 1);
            }

            if ( wordToShorten.contains(lines[0]) ) {
                String shortenedWord = s.replaceAll(wordToShorten, lines[1]);
                shortenedWord = shortened + punctuationChar;
            }
        }
        if ( shortenedWord == wordToShorten ) {
            return wordToShorten;
            }
fileIn.close();
return shortenedWord;
}

this is the otherfile that is used to conduct the shortenWord message on a given word(I have imported java util and java io in the file on my computer:



public class cmdShortener {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        WordShortener WS = new WordShortener();
        String return = WS.shortenWord("hello");
        System.out.println( "Shortened Message:" + return );
        }
}
```

some example lines from abbreviations file seperated by commas (these will not be edited):

eight,8

nine,9

you,u

Comment: Either `inWord` is blank, or it's the other (first) `return` that's returning the empty string.

Comment: Let me ask directly .. for input `eight?` do you want output as `eight'?.!;`

Comment: no, if the input is eight the output should be the number 8

Comment: The constructor which takes a `File` argument and the one which takes a `String` argument are both incorrect because the parameters aren't actually used. What is used instead is the name of the parameter is enclosed in quotes and this does not do what you want. That is, `new File(x)` and `new File("x")` are not equivalent

Comment: Thanks Cyrille Ka. I'll see if I can apply some of your code to ensure mine works correctly :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the loop condition:

```
while ( shortenedWord.equals(inWord) | fileIn.hasNextLine()  )
```

to this:

```
while ( shortenedWord.equals(inWord) && fileIn.hasNextLine()  )
```

Indeed, the loop is continuing as long as you don't find an abbreviation OR there are remaining lines in the file. If you had no more lines, and found no abbreviation, it would then never end.

Also, you should always use the logical operators (`&&` and `||`) instead of the bitwise operator (`&` and `|`) because the formers do not evaluate the rest of the expression if it is not necessary.

**Edit:** I see you are struggling to ask a good question, but you still fail to give code that would compile. So I'm going to try to help you with what I have. Actually, this code is way too complicated for what it tries to achieve. What you want is more something like this:

```
private static final String PUNCTUATIONS = "'?.!;";

public String shortenWord( String inWord ) {

    String originalWord = inWord; // keep track of original input

    // Step 1: get punctuation char and trim inWord to what is needed
    String punctuationChar = "";
    int lengthMinus1 = inWord.length() - 1;
    if (PUNCTUATIONS.contains(inWord.substring(lengthMinus1))) {
        punctuationChar = inWord.substring(lengthMinus1);
        inWord = inWord.substring(0, lengthMinus1);
    }

    while (fileIn.hasNextLine()) {
        // Step 2: get the parts from the line.
        String line = fileIn.nextLine();
        if (line.isEmpty()) {
            continue;
        }
        String[] parts = line.split(",");

        // Step 3: check that inWord is the left part
        if (inWord.equals(parts[0])) {
            // Step 4: return the result
            return parts[1] + punctuationChar;
        }
    }

    // Step 5: if nothing is found, return original.
    fileIn.close();
    return originalWord;
}
```

I hope it's self-explanatory :)

Comment: I've tried this but when I attempt to shorten a word that can be abbreviated (shown below) it returns nothing                  C:\java ShortenuerUtility "hi"
                                                             Shortened Message:

Comment: Can you give the line of the input file relevant for "hi" ?

Comment: Sorry, that should have said can't be abbreviated

Comment: The value `inWord` is not modified in the code you posted. So it can not be `hi` at the beginning and empty in the end. You have some other problem in the parts of code that you haven't shown us.

Comment: I've updated the code a little and placed the command line application I will be using to shorten the message. Theres still the issue of how I return the original word if there is no abbreviation for it.

Comment: The updated code can not compile: in `shortenedWord = Shortened + punctuationChar;`, Shortened is not declared.

Comment: I think you should really give a few lines of your "abbreviations.txt" so we can see what's going on and even reproduce the problem.

Comment: Added a couple of example lines from the abbreviations file and I have now declared the String "shortened"

Answer (score 0):

First of all Don't use `Short` as variable name in your code as Short is itself a class in `java.lang` package.That was the side note. Now your method is returning empty string in this block:

```
if ( inWord.contains(parts[0]) ) {
            String Short = s.replaceAll(inWord, parts[1]);
            shortenedWord = Short + punctuationChar;
                                return shortenedWord;//This is returning blank
        }
```

It might be because `s` is getting value blank in your code.!!

**EDIT** 
Going by your point in comment I think that you need the following code for method `shortenWord`:

```
public String shortenWord( String inWord ) 
{
    String punctuations = "'?.!;"; 
    if (punctuations.contains(String.valueOf(inWord.charAt(inWord.length() - 1)))
    {
        while (fileIn.hasNextLine())
        {
            String read = fileIn.nextLine();
            String parts[] = read.split(",");
            if (parts[0].equals(inWord.substring(0,inWord.length() - 1))))
            {
                return parts[1];
            }
        }

    }  
  fileIn.close();  
  return inWord;
}
```